# Changing button color in cell if clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I'm trying to create like button in `tableview` cell for my project. If like button clicked it must change tint color to red. I'm using Alamofire and if user liked it returns wich feed is liked and in cell:

```
let likerHash = data[indexPath.row]["liker_hash"] as? String
if(likerHash == ""){
   cell.likeButton.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}else{
   cell.likeButton.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

will set color of buttons for feeds. But if i click one button to like if it's not liked it changes color and iwhen i scroll down and come back again button color will change again to previous. (if on loading data it is not liked it will keep color when i scroll down.) I have tride to change value of `liker_hash` but it gives me an error: `mutating method sent to immutable object`. I am tying to change value like:

```
self.data[sender.tag]["liker_hash"] = ""
```

My `data` is from type `[NSMutableDictionary]()`. Any idea how can i do it in swift language?

Comment: Is your tableView reusing its cells? That might be the issue as to why the button resets when your scroll back up.

Comment: i did it using `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell}`. @The_Curry_Man

Comment: I Added an answer. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main feature with using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is that the cell is recreated every time you come back to it. 
Based on the code that you've added, I don't believe you're editing your data source when the user hits the like button to save which cell has been changed the next time the tableView reloads.

What I'd suggest is holding all the cells in an array. Supposed you have 5 cells, create an array holding their current state:

```
var cellArr = ["Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black"]
```

Then, if the user selects the like button, make sure to update this array with the right color as well. So if I select the second row, I update it like:

```
var cellArr = ["Black", "Red", "Black", "Black", "Black"]
```

And then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
if cellArr[indexPath.row] == "Black"{
    cell.likeButton.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor() }
else {
    cell.likeButton.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

Comment: I will try it tomottow and reply there. I understand what you mean and i think it will work. But if i dont need to recreat cell every time, how can i change my code to do that?

Comment: And is that true if when i do without 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier'?

Comment: Using 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier' is a good practice. It ensures that your app doesn't cause memory leaks, etc. I would not consider not to use it.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Then i will create a new array and save there all cell button colors, and then if some of them will change i will update it in array. I will try it tomorrow and reply back. Thanks for help.

Comment: Thanks man. It works perfect. if someone search answer: At first i have created array like this: `var likeArray: [String] = [];` then i added all colors to my array. and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` i checked if this black or red color is. Thats all. Thanks to @The_Curry_Man for help.

Comment: Haha, no problem :) Glad I could help!